# Optimisation with JAX using vmap or foriloop

Tags: python, optimization, jax

I'm still encountering a challenge with optimizing my code using the JAX library. The purpose of this code is to apply a blur to an intensity array by creating a normalized Gaussian for each pixel and adding it to another intensity array. Currently, I'm using the Numba library to achieve this. However, for the sake of optimization, I'd like to switch to the JAX library, which I've noticed is faster.

I've tried two different approaches. The first involves using Vmap, while the second relies on a fori loop. Unfortunately, neither approach yields the same result as what I get with Numba. I'm struggling to understand the reason behind this discrepancy in results.

Another issue has emerged: the code seems to run slower with JAX than with Numba (time with JAX Vmap: 0.01026153564453125 s, time with JAX fori loop: 0.0016379356384277344 s, time with Numba: 0.0004425048828125 s).

I'm seeking your assistance to guide me towards an effective optimization of this code, please.

Here is the current code:

```
intensityRefracted2DF = np.random.rand(10, 10)
intensityRefracted31 = np.zeros((10, 10))
darkField = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,10))
intensityRefracted31=np.pad(intensityRefracted31, 20, mode='constant')
darkField=np.pad(darkField, 20, mode='constant')
intensityRefracted2DF=np.pad(intensityRefracted2DF, 20, mode='constant')

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def darkFieldLoop1(margin2, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField, Nx, Ny):

    for i in range(20, Nx + 20):
        for j in range(20, Ny + 20):
            if intensityRefracted2DF[i, j] != 0 and darkField[i, j] != 0:
                
                currDF = darkField[i, j]
                patch = gaussian_shape2(currDF)
                size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2
                patch = patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
            
                intensityRefracted3[i - size2:i + size2 + 1, j - size2:j + size2 + 1] += patch
            elif darkField[i, j] == 0:
                intensityRefracted3[i, j] += intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
    return intensityRefracted3

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def gaussian_shape2(sigma):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.

    Args:
        sigma (float): Standard deviation of the Gaussian shape.

    Returns:
        exponent (2D numpy array): Gaussian shape.
    """
    dim = int(2 * np.ceil(3 * sigma) + 1)
    x = np.arange(0, dim) - np.floor((dim - 1) / 2)
    exponent = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = exponent * exponent[:,np.newaxis]
    return exponent / np.sum(exponent)


intensityRefracted3=np.zeros_like(intensityRefracted31)

TIME1=time.time()

c = darkFieldLoop1(0, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField, 10, 10)
time2 = time.time()-TIME1
```

[image: expected result]

Code using vmap for jax :

```
@jax.jit
def darkFieldLoop(intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    currDF = jnp.zeros_like(intensityRefracted3)
    currDF = jnp.where(jnp.logical_and(intensityRefracted2DF!=0,darkField!=0),darkField,0)

    i = jnp.nonzero(currDF,size=(currDF.shape[0]*currDF.shape[1])+1)
    indices_i=i[0]
    indices_j=i[1]
    darkField = darkField.at[indices_i[-1],indices_j[-1]].set(1)

    intensityRefracted3= jax.vmap(apply_dark_field, in_axes=(0, 0, None, None, None))(indices_i, indices_j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField)
    intensityRefracted3 = jnp.sum(intensityRefracted3,axis=0)
    return intensityRefracted3

@jax.jit
def apply_dark_field(i, j, intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    patch = gaussian_shape(darkField[i,j],20)
    size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2

    start_indices = (i - size2+1, j - size2+1)
    update = jax.lax.dynamic_slice(intensityRefracted3, start_indices, patch.shape)
    patch = patch * intensityRefracted2DF[i, j]
    update += patch
    intensityRefracted3 = jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice(
        intensityRefracted3, update,  start_indices)
    
    return intensityRefracted3

@partial(jax.jit,static_argnums=(1,))
def gaussian_shape(sigma, size):

    x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor((size-1) / 2)
    exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    exponent = exponent * exponent[:,np.newaxis]
    return exponent / jnp.sum(exponent)



intensityRefracted3=np.zeros_like(intensityRefracted31)

TIME9=time.time()

g=darkFieldLoop(intensityRefracted2DF,intensityRefracted3,darkField)

time9 = time.time()-TIME9
```

I also tried to optimize it using foriloop:

```
@partial(jax.jit)
def darkFieldLoop12(intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField):
    currDF = jnp.zeros_like(intensityRefracted3)
    currDF = jnp.where(darkField!=0,darkField,0)

    i = jnp.nonzero(currDF,size=(currDF.shape[0]*currDF.shape[1])+1)
    indices_i=i[0]
    indices_j=i[1]

    darkField = darkField.at[indices_i[-1],indices_j[-1]].set(1)



    def loop_body(i, carry):
    
        indices_i,indices_j,intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, DF= carry
    
        patch= gaussian_shape5(indices_i[i], indices_j[i], DF)
        patch=patch*intensityRefracted2DF[indices_i[i],indices_j[i]]
        size2 = patch.shape[0] // 2
        start_indices = (indices_i[i] - size2, indices_j[i] - size2)
        update = jax.lax.dynamic_slice(intensityRefracted3, start_indices, patch.shape)
   
        update += patch
        intensityRefracted3 = jax.lax.dynamic_update_slice(
            intensityRefracted3, update,  start_indices)
    
    
       return (indices_i,indices_j,intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, DF)

    carry = (indices_i,indices_j,intensityRefracted2DF, intensityRefracted3, darkField)
    _,_,_, intensityRefracted3, _ = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, indices_i.shape[0], loop_body, carry)

return intensityRefracted3



@partial(jax.jit)
def gaussian_shape5(i,j,DF):

    sigma=DF[i,j]
    size= 20
    sigma_sqrt= 2*(sigma**2)
    x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor((size-1) / 2)
    exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (sigma_sqrt))
    exponent = exponent * exponent[:,jnp.newaxis]
    return exponent / jnp.sum(exponent)

intensityRefracted3=np.zeros_like(intensityRefracted31)

TIME9=time.time()

x=darkFieldLoop12(intensityRefracted2DF,intensityRefracted3,darkField)

time9 = time.time()-TIME9
```

Here are the obtained results, and it's noticeable that they are not the same. The execution time is longer, and furthermore, I'm struggling to define the size of the Gaussian in the same way as for Numba (size = int(2 * np.ceil(3 * sigma) + 1)).

[image]

Comment: *"for the sake of optimization, I'd like to switch to the JAX library, which I've noticed is faster."* There is no reason to believe Numba is slower in general, at least, for basic loops on arrays like here. For example, Numba can generate code competing with fastest native C BLAS implementations if used correctly. In fact, your observation tends to prove the opposite: *"run slower with JAX than with Numba"*. By the way, the Numba code seems inefficient : `gaussian_shape2`, called in the nested loops, creates small temporary arrays, which are expensive (due to allocations).

Comment: Moreover, It does not make much sense to compare the performance of code having very different results. Bugs often strongly impact performance. The codes need to be fixed first to give the same result (or approximately the same). Which one is supposed to be correct? The later? My guess is that the difference comes from types (eg. casting/promotion). I advise you to check the computation is done using floating-point numbers and not integers (unless this is what you need).

Comment: By the way `gaussian_shape2` can be precomputed for the 10 different possible inputs. It should be much faster since computing `exp` tends to be expensive and `gaussian_shape2` is called 100 times (10x more).

Comment: @JérômeRichard 
Hello, thank you for your response. Regarding the desire to use JAX for its speed, this is because I also want the calculations to be performed on a potential GPU. I read in a post [link](https://github.com/google/jax/discussions/11078) that JAX's CPU and GPU implementations seem to be fastest when using loops. Therefore, given my results, which show the opposite in my case, I am questioning my code implementation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard
Additionally, I forgot to mention that the codes indeed produce the exact same results when the standard deviation of the Gaussian is less than 1. The results diverged when I increased the standard deviations. That's why I had already compared the performances.
Thank you again for your response. I will check the data types as well as optimize the Gaussian generation.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any other ideas for optimizing this code?

Comment: Have you configured `jax` to use double-precision? The default is single, and functions like exp will be sensitive to this.

Comment: @DavidJ Thank you for your response. I haven't configured JAX for double precision. Should all the variables be changed to float64?

Comment: I haven't implemented the code, and don't know if this is the contributing factor. However, for a fair comparison with Numba it should be used. See [Sharp bits: double precision](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#double-64bit-precision)

Comment: JAX is faster on the link because of XLA and more specifically because of kernel fusion. Such a task can be done manually though it may be cumbersome (but often a bit faster), especially on GPUs. AFAIK Numba can do that in some restricted context but often fail to do it. I consider this as a (nice) feature rather than better raw performance. Numba also supports GPU computation, though it might be lower-level (you need to write a kernel yourself), though it is generally good for skilled developpers to write these kernels manually for better performance (so it depends of your needs).

Comment: Note that XLA is I think mostly interesting when a kernel is rather memory bound. It avoid saturating memory by storing and reloading data from the main RAM. For compute bound kernels, I do not expect a significant improvement. Inlining might help in some critical cases though.

Comment: Numpy create double-precision (DP) arrays by default (eg. for `np.random.rand(10, 10)`). If you do not need that, please specify `dtype=np.float32` in argument of Numpy functions like that to use single-precision (SP, faster and less precise). Physics simultation often requires DP, while image computation is fine with SP. Machine-learning task can even often use half-precision (possibly mixed with SP). Note that client-side GPUs are only good for SP (very slow for DP, often slower than CPUs). Server-side GPUs are good for HP, SP and DP but they are way more expensive.

Comment: I strongly advise to optimise your code on CPUs first, and only use GPUs if it is still not fast enough (possibly only for some specific kernels). GPUs codes are often more complex to maintain and sometimes to implement efficiently. Moreover, not all codes are faster on GPUs (strongly dependent of the target task). Besides, I do not expect a GPU to give a very good speed up for tasks running in less than 0.5 ms. Also please note that the CPU code might be parallelized.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you very much for your help and explanations. I will first optimize my code for the CPU before attempting to implement it on the GPU. As I am not an expert in programming, I believe this approach seems more sensible. The most time-consuming part is the generation of the normalized Gaussian.

Comment: @JérômeRichard By modifying the code to generate non-integer random numbers but rather floating-point values: 'darkField = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(100, 100))'
The time to generate the Gaussian increases significantly when choosing a standard deviation of 'dim = int(2 * np.ceil(3 * sigma) + 1)' . Additionally, will it still be possible to precompute the Gaussians? Do you perhaps have an idea for optimizing this part, maybe by setting the value of dim? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The key point is to first fix the bug, even if it makes the code slower. Once results will be the same, and only then we should optimize it, and find why it is now slower. To quote Donald Knuth: *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*. That being said, integers tends to be faster to compute than FP numbers because of the higher latency of FP instructions not to mention DP FP numbers are twice bigger than 32-bit integers (the default type of integer on Windows).

Comment: The above pre-computation is only possible if the number of possible input is small so not with FP numbers. There is certainly other optimisations that can be done though (e.g. removing the temporary arrays and perform everything on the fly).

Comment: Thank you for your help.
First, I will try to understand why the results between the code using Jax and the one using Numba do not return the same result. Then, I will focus on optimizing the code.